# What exception should I throw and should I provide a message?

Tags: c#, exception

I have a situation where a user operation changes the current status of a request.

Depending on the current status then only certain operations are possible i.e.

Pending can be Approved or Rejected or Cancelled
Approved can be 'Cancel Requested'
'Cancel Requested' can be 'Cancellation Approved' or 'Cancellation Requested'

My question is what type of exception should I raise if the requested operation cannot be carried out? Should I use an inbuilt exception or should I create a custom exception such as InvalidCurrentStatusException or some such?

Looking at the documentation for InvalidOperationException seems a prime candidate as it is 'the exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state'.

If I go with the second option of a custom exception then I don't need to provide a message.

If I use the inbuilt InvalidOperationException should I provide a message and what should that message be?

UPDATE:

here's the code I have at the moment:

```
internal void CancelRequest(int requestID, int userID, string notes)
{

        DateTime editDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

        var request = this.FindByID(requestID, CancelRequestIncludes);

        if(request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(InvalidRequestMessage);
        }

        var currentStatus = request.LeaveRequestStatuses.Where(s => s.IsCurrent).FirstOrDefault();

        if (currentStatus.StatusID == (int)RequestStatuses.RequestPending)
        {
            SetNewRequestStatus(request, currentStatus, RequestStatuses.CancellationApproved, userID, notes, editDate);
        }
        else if (currentStatus.StatusID == (int)RequestStatuses.RequestApproved)
        {
            if (ValidApprover(request.UserID, userID))
            {
                SetNewRequestStatus(request, currentStatus, RequestStatuses.CancellationPending, userID, notes, editDate);
            }
            else
            {
                //throw an invalid approver exceptioon

            }
        }
        else
        {
            //throw exception as cant carry out cancellation
        }

        Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I prefer to use custom exceptions for my code and system exceptions for system classes. This can help you when you don't know where is the error and why.

Comment: If you can detect that the request is invalid, why throw an exception at all versus an error message of some sort.  Or better, disable the invalid options conditionally so the user cant do Bad Things.

Comment: I agree with @Plutonix: in this case instead of throwing exception you can use a sort of "Application Status" property and Enumeration (Approved, Rejected, Cancelled). Best regards,

Comment: @Plutonix you shouldn't rely on upstream code to handle the correctness

Comment: Nor should you use Exceptions for program flow control nor for situations your code can detect.  Exceptions are for exceptional situations (hence the clever name) not simple data validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never use an `Exception` (or any subclass) to control the state of the application, or indicate logical flow. Instead you should create a class that acts as a "result" in which you add a property that has the "status" -- as some others have already commented an enum is a prime example of a desirable use-case.

```
public enum RequestStatus
{
    Approved,
    Rejected,
    Cancelled,
    UnableToCarryOut
}

public class RequestResult
{
    public RequestStatus Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Then simply pass around an instance of this object.

Comment: This is how I usually do things but many things I have seen and read recently seem to imply that you should use an exception.

Comment: I'm curious what you're reading. I still believe you should not throw unless it's truly exceptional.

Comment: I was just reading this http://codeutopia.net/blog/2010/03/11/should-a-failed-function-return-a-value-or-throw-an-exception/ and it seems to support your (and my usual) method of using a return 'code': 'An often forgotten fact is application stability. If you are writing critical code that should be as stable as possible, what should you use? Return values.'

Comment: This blog is six years old. But I still agree with the result object over exception for flow. If I answered your question, please accept my answer. Thank you

Comment: Just because its six years old doesn't mean its invalid. The GoF patterns book is over 15 years old and its still valid!

Comment: Here is an argument for using exceptions: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/exceptions-vs-status.html

Comment: Is this "request" and HTTP request? If so you would never want to return an HttpStatus of 500, the server should return something meaningful to the client

Comment: Just looking at the Hanselman blog - granted its a post from 2006 but I think it's still valid today - he supports your view and what I have traditionally done: 'Exceptions are exceptional and should be treated as such. If something exceptional, unusual, or generally "not supposed to ordinarily happen" then an exception is a reasonable thing to do.
You shouldn't throw exceptions for things that happen all the time. Then they'd be "ordinaries".'

Comment: In this case while in my case the situation shouldn't arise frequently it can arise to a web page sitting open for some time while someone else has carried out the operation so it's not exceptional - a missing request is exceptional so I still believe I should throw the InvalidArgumentException.

Answer (score 0):

Custom exception would be the best option in this case. And you've guessed it right - there should be two types of those (as your comments suggest).
The classes for those should be named to be self-describing:
- InvalidApproverException
- UnexpectedStatusException

Both can actually be derieved or even replaced by InvalidOperationException, but then you'll have to provide similar exception message every time. The good thing about custom exceptions is that you can add some more information about the context of the exception. Specifically, the InvalidApproverException - can expose the actual approver's id, who for the operation has failed. This could be useful later down the road. Also - it can internally set the message to some constant string: something similar to: "The caller is not the initiator of the request".
As or the second exception (UnexpectedStatusException) - I'd expose the CurrentRequestStatus property on it as well and again have a constant error message. That just simplifies the handling down the road. Here is a sample code for the exception:

public class UnexpectedStatusException : Exception
{
    private const string DefaultExceptionMessage = "The request is not in an expected state.";

```
public LeaveRequestStatus CurrentStatus
{
    get; private set;
}

public UnexpectedStatusException(LeaveRequestStatus currentStatus) : this(currentStatus, DefaultExceptionMessage)
{
}

public UnexpectedStatusException(LeaveRequestStatus currentStatus, string message) : base(message)
{
    this.CurrentStatus = currentStatus;
}
```

}

public enum LeaveRequestStatus
{
    // Request statueses here
}